# Is it possible to write an app to interface and activate the underlying linux kernel device driver?

Tags: android-kernel

I have a simple device driver activated, and I wonder if I can write an app that would interface with it. That is activate the functions such as open(), ioctl(), etc. 
I have compiled an executable which I wrote in C, and it does the same thing. But I want to implement this in an app so I can run it quickly and interface with the program via a UI. 
I am looking at implementing this with JNI; I wonder if there an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control over the kernel driver then its possible to do it purely in Java. Just use RandomAccessFile with read&write. You will not be able to call ioctl though